# How can $\Bbb RP^1 \cong S^1$ be true if they have different cardinalities?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, projective-space

> Prove that $\Bbb RP^1 \cong S^1$

$$\Bbb R P^1= \{[(x_0, x_1)]: (x_0, x_1) \in \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \text{ and } (x_0, x_1) \sim(y_0, y_1) \text{ iff } (x_0,x_1) = \lambda(y_0, y_1) \text{ for some $\lambda \in R-\{0\}$  }\}$$

is the set of lines through the origin, excluding the origin, and

$S^1 = \{(z_1,z_2) \in \Bbb R \times \Bbb R : z_1^2 + z_2^2=1\}$.

Superimposing the two on the plane you can see that each line through the origin intersects the circle in exactly two antipodal points.

But wouldn't this imply a map between the two spaces couldn't be bijective since one has the cardinality of points on a circle and the other would have the cardinality of points on the hemi-circle?

Comment: They do have the same cardinality, viz., $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Just because there is a two-to-one surjective map from one set to another, it does not follow that there is no one-to-one surjective map. You may be thinking about finite sets where that is not possible, but these are infinite sets where that is indeed possible.

Comment: Also, just because there is a nonsurjective one-to-one map from one set to another, it does not follow that there is no surjective one-to-one map. Again, the behavior here is different between finite sets and infinite sets.

Comment: I don't see how they have the same cardinality.  If $\Bbb R P$ is the identification of a line through the origin without the origin, then why isn't it the case that the distinct set of lines are the ones whose rotation about the origin goes between $0 \le \theta \lt \pi$?

Comment: @OliverG You need to think more about the definition of cardinality. These examples might help. (1) The integers and the even integers have the same cardinality: multiplication by $2$ is a bijection between them. (2) The interval $(0,1)$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5):

There is a homeomorphism between ${\mathbb R}P^1$ and $S^1$ allright, but it is slightly more involved than your map. You arrived at a $1:2$ correspondence. Now think about a map that makes out of two opposite points on $S^2$ one single point on $S^2$ in a nice way. A hint: Maybe you remember $z\mapsto z^2$ from complex analysis.

To expand on the hint: The map $\psi:\ z\mapsto z^2$ restricted to $S^1\subset{\mathbb C}$ maps two opposite points $\pm z\in S^1$ to one single point. Now consider the map $\psi\circ f$, where $f$ is the map you hinted at in your question.

Comment: I can't find a homeomorphism with that hint, I'm thinking along the lines of $[z] \mapsto z^2$ where $z$ represents a point in $\Bbb RP$, but it's not a function.

Comment: I'm not sure what function $f$ I was hinting at in my question.  But I don't see how a map could map from $[z]$ and end up with $z^2$ and still be a function.

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{R}P^1$ and $S^1$ are both 1-dimensional compact connected topological manifolds, and there is only one such manifold up to homeomorphisms. Therefore they are homeormorphic and have the same cardinality.

Comment: The book hasn't covered manifolds yet, is there a way to show this without referring to them?